# Exchange 2010 - Disable Address Rewrite per Account

Tags: exchange-2010, aliases

Is it possible to disable for only one account the address rewrite in Exchange 2010 ?

I have 1 emails : 
helpdesk@mycompany.org

With 2 aliases :
Helpdesk.international@mycompany.org
Helpdesk.local@mycompany.org

I want to fetch all emails that are received with "To=Helpdesk.international@mycompany.org" but not the other one. So far the "To" field is always set to helpdesk@mycompany.org.

PS : It cannot be disable for all users.

TIA,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you're asking but it sounds to me like you want to set a specific email address as the primary SMTP address for this user other than the one being set by your email address policy. If so, then go into EMC>Recipient Configuration>Mailbox and bring up the properties of the user in question, then go to the E-mail Addresses tab, then unselect the check box "Automatically update e-mail addresses based on e-mail address policy", then select the email address that you want to be the primary SMTP address and click the "Set as Reply" button.

Comment: I want to be able to keep the "To:" field set to the alias. For the moment the To field is always re written with the principal email address. Thanks.

Comment: I just did the test and it doesn't change anything. the To field is still the principal email address.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Do you mean the To field in a new email message? If so, then delete that entry from your nickname cache and retype the email address that you want to show up.

Comment: Ok it's an Outlook problem then, you are right with the option "Automatically update e-mail addresses based on e-mail address policy" disabled and Thunderbird as the client, the To: field is set correctly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help...